# SQL after trigger is not working as expected in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, bulkinsert

I am writing a simple SQL Server `After insert` trigger for a table.

Through a stored procedure, I am inserting bulk values into the table from the SQL table type.

When I am inserting more than one row, the trigger only triggers once.
Why is it I don't know.

This is my query

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP_LOOKUP_NON_BULK (OPERATION_ID, CAST_CODE_ID, CAST_CODE_SRNO_ID, QUANTITY, IS_BULK,CREATED_ON) 
    SELECT TOP 1
        @OPERATOIN_ID, @CAST_CODE_ID_FromCastCodeMappingTable,
        [CAST_CODE_SR_NO_ID], 1, 0, GETDATE()
    FROM 
        #TEMP_TRN_CAST_CODE_SHELL_MAPPING
```

Trigger code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_LOOKUP_NON_BULK_TRANSACTION]
ON [dbo].[LOOKUP_NON_BULK_TRANSACTION]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN--1    
    INSERT INTO LOGCHECK (CALLINGPAGE, OPERATION) 
    VALUES ('TRIGGER TRIGGER NMO BULK', 'TRIGGER TRIGGER NMO BULK') 
END
```

Comment: Please show the trigger code. Maybe you are not treating the data affected as a set but as rows?

Comment: I have written just the insert script into my trigger for checking

Comment: Please check jpw i have added trigger code

Comment: Triggers only fire once per statement, so this is expected. In your trigger you don't do anything that references the inserted data - if this is the actual code, then what would be the point of inserting multiple identical rows into the logcheck table?

Comment: That is the way SQL Server works! You get a trigger **once per statement** - not per row. If your `INSERT` statement inserts 20 rows, your `Inserted` pseudo table in the trigger will contain **20 rows** and you need to code your trigger to be able to cope with that situation

Comment: Thanks for giving me suggestions I reallly appreciate your time given to me